# Почему не отображается div пока по консоли браузера не протянуть мышкой?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Я использую `div owerlay` для затемнения экрана во время всплывающего сообщения.

Нажимаю на кнопку, появляется сообщение, экран затемнился. Закрываю сообщение. Заново нажимаю на кнопку, сообщение появляется, а экран не затемняется!

Причем если нажать правую кнопку и в выпадающем списке выбрать "*Просмотр кода элемента*", то затемнение резко появляется. Появляется  так же, кода просматриваю `html` страницы в инспекторе и просто мышкой проведу по дереву `html`.

Причем, `div` появляется, на него навешен клик и он работает. Такое впечатление что браузер не рисует затемнение))

Что это такое? Как исправить такую странность?

Использую браузер *Google Chrome*. PS Проверил в *мозиле*, там все ок.

Comment: ошибка в 17 строке.

Comment: Вы о чем??

Comment: Какая версия Chrome?

Comment: @MatthewPatell, вам намекают, чтобы вы показали свой код.

Comment: Была аналогичная проблема, решение в ответе http://hashcode.ru/questions/311635/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9

Comment: Во! Heidel, спасибо огромное! То, что нужно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После того, как показываешь оверлей, перед последующими действиями найди его и запроси его ширину. Это заставит браузер сделать reflow и он гарантированно отобразится.